# Oracle Sql cumulative sum by month and user

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an table like below in oracle

| USER | YEAR | MONTH | POINT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2020 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2020 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 2020 | 3 | 1 |

now I want to get table like below

| USER | YEAR | MONTH | POINT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2020 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2020 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2020 | 3 | 2 |

I tried below but not working what I expected

```
SELECT A_YEAR,A_MONTH,USER, SUM(POINTT) OVER (ORDER BY A_YEAR,A_MONTH,USER) CUM_POINT
FROM (
    SELECT WA.USER, WA.A_YEAR,WA.A_MONTH,1 AS POINTT FROM HRANALY.PUAN_ACTUAL PA
    INNER JOIN HRANALY.WAGE_ACTUAL WA ON WA.USER= PA.USER AND WA.A_YEAR = PA.A_YEAR AND WA.A_MONTH = PA.A_MONTH
    INNER JOIN HRANALY.PUAN_ACTUAL_DETAIL PAD ON PAD.REF_WAGE=PA.ID AND PAD.KALEM_KOD='GRUP_HEDEF' AND PAD.AMOUNT>0
    ORDER BY a_month
)
ORDER BY A_YEAR,A_MONTH,USER;
```

in this query CUM_POINT goes from 1 to n not working as user year month based
How can I get second table with query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need analytical function as follows:

```
select user_id, year, month,
       sum(point) over (partition by user_id order by year, month) as points
  from t
```

In ytour query just add partition by clause as follows:

```
SUM(POINTT) OVER (PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY A_YEAR,A_MONTH,USER) CUM_POINT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select x.*, 
       sum(point) over (partition by year, month, userid) sum_point
from foo x
```

[image]